# Using Series with Refine or Assuming to restrict the power

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, assumptions

I have a system of differential equations which contain a singular point.  To avoid the singular point, I am expanding the coefficients and solutions in a power series around that point.

Due to the physical problem, these coefficients have expansions

$f_1(t) = \frac{n+1}{\Gamma_1 t}\left(1 - \frac{(3k^n)}{n+1} t^{n+1}\right)$

$f_2(t) = (3k^n)\left(1 +(n-3) t + \frac{2(3k^n)}{(n+1)(n+2)} t^{n+1}\right)$

$f_3(t) = \frac{A_s}{t}\left(1 - \frac{(3k^n)}{n+1} t^{n+1}\right)$

$f_4(t) = 1 - 3t + \frac{3k^n}{n+1} t^{n+1}$

which contain inverse powers, small powers, and powers at $n+1$, where $n$ is an exponent from the physical problem itself.

The solutions to the dif. eqs. are suspected to be a power series of the form

$y_i(t) = y_{i0} + y_{i1}t + \cdots + y_{in} t^n + y_{i,n+1} t^{n+1} + \cdots,$

where $y_i$ is one of the solutions.

I define all the functions as series expansions, I put them into the diff. eqs., and I try want to solve order-by-order using, for instance

```
SeriesCoefficient[ode1[l, t], {t, 0, -1}]==0
```

Mathematica won't handle that very well, but for good reason.  Depending on the value of $n$, the powers $t^n, t^{n+1}$ might enter at any given order.  So I try to help Mathematica out by letting it know that $n>1$, so that powers of $n$ or higher can be ignored at this order.  So I write

```
Refine[SeriesCoefficient[ode1[l, t], {t, 0, -1}], n >= 1] == 0
```

However, Mathematica still isn't happy and still won't produce a result, even though it should now know to ignore powers $t^n$ or higher.

Trying instead

```
Refine[SeriesCoefficient[ode1[l, t], {t, 0, -1}], n ==2] == 0
```

works.  It produces a result at the correct order and without $t^n$ terms.  The problem with this is that $n$ also enters at the coefficient-level, and I don't want a "2" in the answer it gives, but "n".

How can I use `Refine` with `Series` and `SeriesCoefficient` to let Mathematica know that a variable power $n$ is larger than some value so can be left out of low-order results?

---

To help you help me, below are code snippets

```
(*coefficient functions*)
 r[t_] := R (1 - t);
 f1[t_] := (n + 1)/(G t) (1 - (3 k^n)/(n + 1) t^(n + 1));
 f2[t_] := (3 k^n) t^n (1 - (3 - n) t + (2 (3 k^n))/((n + 1) (n + 2)) t^(n + 1));
 f3[t_] := (n - (n + 1)/G)/t (1 - (3 k^n)/(n + 1) t^(n + 1));
 f4[t_] := 1 - 3 t + (3 k^n)/(n + 1) t^(n + 1);

(*solutions*)
 y1[t_] := W[0] + W[1] t + W[n] t^n + W[n + 1] t^(n + 1) + W[2 n + 1] t^(2 n + 1);
 y2[t_] := X[0] + X[1] t + X[n] t^n + X[n + 1] t^(n + 1) + X[2 n + 1] t^(2 n + 1);
 y3[t_] := Y[0] + Y[1] t + Y[n] t^n + Y[n + 1] t^(n + 1) + Y[2 n + 1] t^(2 n + 1);
 y4[t_] := Z[0] + Z[1] t + Z[n] t^n + Z[n + 1] t^(n + 1) + Z[2 n + 1] t^(2 n + 1);

(*the first ode*)
 ode1[l_, t_] := -(r[t]/R) D[y1[t], t]*(-1) +(f1[t] - (l + 1)) y1[t] + (l (l + 1)/(f4[t]*w^2) - f1[t]) y2[t] + f1[t] y3[t];
```

Answer (score 3):

Could use `Series` to some modest degree, then `Normal`, then wipe out terms with factors of `t` to some power involving `n` (this assumes it is known it will always be a positive times `n`). After that, `SeriesCoefficient` should be fine for handling what remains.

That example:

```
ee = Expand[Normal[Series[ode1[l, t], {t, 0, 2}]]] /. 
   t^j_ /; ! FreeQ[j, n] :> 0;
SeriesCoefficient[ee, {t, 0, -1}]

(* Out[979]= (W[0] + n W[0] - X[0] - n X[0] + Y[0] + n Y[0])/G *)
```

Comment: I've tried `Normal@Series` before and it didn't do anything useful.  I don't know what your `/.t^j_/; ! FreeQ[j,n]:>0` part does.  But, it seems to work!  Thanks!

Comment: It removes (that is, zeros) any power of `t` that contains `n`. Basically a way of saying "these terms are too small for retaining, replace them with zero".

Comment: At least in this case, `Expand` and `Normal` don't seem needed. I obtain the same result without them.

Comment: @MarcoB It is probably safe to not expand (or use `Normal`) except when symbolic powers might cancel. And in such cases one would require extra code to not remove negative symbolic powers for example.